# When setting state with React's use state hook using it's prev (or initial) value throws an error Type Error 0 is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a very basic setup of providers. I'm sure my component is wrapped within the provider and the value should be passed to the child component.

```
const { totalData } = useContext(Context);
const [setTotal] = totalData;
```

I'm extracting a set method here to set a total cost of selected items. and on my Provider side

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
```

and I'm exposing this state like so

```
 <Context.Provider
  value={{
    totalData: [total, setTotal],
  }}>
  {props.children}
</Context.Provider>
```

when a button is pressed in this case a React Native TouchableOpacity I'm setting the state like so;

```
setTotal(prev => checked ? prev + item.total_cost : prev - item.total_cost)
```

any ideas on how this might happen is really appreciated.

**Thanks!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using arrays to store your value and setter function where you're setting `total` as the first value (index `0`) and `setTotal` as the second value (index `1`).

The problem with this is when you write `const [setTotal] = totalData;` you are actually grabbing the first value in the `totalData` array (which is `total`) and renaming it as `setTotal`.

So now you're trying to call `setTotal()` but you're effectively writing `total()` which gives you that error.

**Solution:**

It would be a better developer experience to store these values as keys in an object so that you can destructure them the way you want to.

Change you context provider this:

```
<Context.Provider value={{ totalData: { total, setTotal } }}>
  {props.children}
</Context.Provider>
```

Then use it like this:

```
const { totalData } = useContext(Context);
const { setTotal } = totalData;
```

**Note:**

If you really want to keep using arrays like you originally have been doing this, then you can destructure it like this:

```
const [_, setTotal] = totalData;
// Or
const setTotal = totalData[1];
```

This way you are grabbing the second item in your array (the set function), and simple ignoring the first (`total`) value.

Comment: I'm using other state hooks like the one I'm using here, and destructing them the same way. I can see the total value is 0 when initialized but when the state changes via ```setTotal``` it throws this error

Comment: See my edited answer to explain your answer in more detail

Comment: I've added a **Note** section for how you might keep following your current pattern effectively.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it just need to update the other references. I've used this approach to avoid re-rendering multiple children at the same time but it still seems to keep doing that. I'll look deeper in to this.

Comment: Ah right, yeah the thing with this is it will still rerender your children because when a parent updates children update too. The solution is general to working on improving how the children are rendering, e.g. making use of `useCallback` and `useMemo` in the children so that rerenders don't do as many computations etc.